# Javascript stopped working after switching to another display

Tags: javascript, html, css

Each time I change displays within one HTML file JS stops working (I've tried to replace HTML `onclick` call with JS function, but it's still the same)

UPD: Sorry for bad explanation. The problem is that if I move from the main display of this site by clicking links on `nav` panel (e.g. from `#main` to `#contacts` or `#cart`) JS script stops responding on burger icon click (clicking on burger nav panel for screen max-width of 800px doing nothing)

Code:

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger i');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

function toggleNav() {
  burger.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
  burger.classList.toggle('fa-times');
  nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
}

burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleNav();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #343434;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343434;
  border-top: 1px solid #343434;
}

.logo {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;
}

.navlink {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.navlink a {
  color: #343434;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.burger {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    top: 70px;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 400ms;
  }
  .navlink {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-active {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./site.css">
  <script src="site.js" type="javascript"></script>
  <title>Атлас</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" style="display:block">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#main"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Атлас - мы волокем в оптоволокне!" onclick="document.getElementById('main').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('main').style.display='block';"></a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#contacts" onclick="document.getElementById('main').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='block';">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#delivery" onclick="document.getElementById('main').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='block';">Доставка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#cart" onclick="document.getElementById('main').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('cart').style.display='block';">Корзина</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div id="contacts" style="display:none">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#main"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Атлас - мы волокем в оптоволокне!" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('main').style.display='block';"></a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#contacts" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='block';">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#delivery" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='block';">Доставка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#cart" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('cart').style.display='block';">Корзина</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div id="delivery" style="display:none">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#main"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Атлас - мы волокем в оптоволокне!" onclick="document.getElementById('about').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('main').style.display='block';"></a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#contacts" onclick="document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='block';">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#delivery" onclick="document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='block';">Доставка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#cart" onclick="document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('cart').style.display='block';">Корзина</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div id="cart" style="display:none">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#main"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Атлас - мы волокем в оптоволокне!" onclick="document.getElementById('cart').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('main').style.display='block';"></a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#contacts" onclick="document.getElementById('cart').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('contacts').style.display='block';">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#delivery" onclick="document.getElementById('cart').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('delivery').style.display='block';">Доставка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlink"><a href="#cart" onclick="document.getElementById('cart').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('cart').style.display='block';">Корзина</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <script src="./site.js"></script>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div id="payment" style="display:none">

  </div>
  <script src="./site.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem. Please give a step by step how to reprodice the issue

Comment: It's great that you have shown the relevant code, but you've not given enough detail to identify the problem. eg when you say "stops working" do you see any javascript errors on the console?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "switching display"? Show the screen on another screen? Changing the size of the window?

Comment: Sidenote: Why have you got `<script src="./site.js"></script>` so many times in your html??

Comment: Never include script in the header unless you are using defer or  async attributes with the script tag.

Comment: Describe your problem, please, and we will definitely help you

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation. The problem is that if I move from the main display of this site by clicking links on nav panel (e.g. from #main to #contacts or #cart) js script stops working (clicking on burger nav panel for screen max-width of 800px doing nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have several `.burger` in your HTML and you only define a Javascript event for the very first one. You could remedy this via:

```
const burgers = document.querySelectorAll('.burger i');
```

and

```
for (let burger of burgers) {
    //define your event
}
```

but it's not the best approach. The very best thing that you could do is to refactor your HTML and have a single item with the `.burger` `class`, but with more reliable event.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes the problem was in duplication (dummy placing the header in each display...)